# What should be the name of the prev_node argument passed into the method given below?

Tags: java, linked-list, parameter-passing, nodes

```
public class linkedList {
  Node head;

   class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d){
      data  = d;
    }
  }    
    public void insertAfter(Node prev_node, int new_data){
    if (prev_node == null){
      System.out.print("The given previous node cannot be null");
      return;
    }
    Node new_node = new Node(new_data);
    new_node.next = prev_node.next;
    prev_node.next = new_node;
  }
}
```

For a given linked list: `11,73,80,41,22`, if I'd want to insert a number (eg. 0) after 73, I can pass it as `insertAfter(llist.head.next,0)`.

But that is as far as I can reach to name a **prev_node**. What goes in as argument if I wanted to enter the 0 after the third,fourth...etc position. What will the argument be then ?

PS : Forgive me if the title is misleading or confusing, I wasn't able to put the query in right words for the title.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are you asking for a meaningful name for `prev_node` argument? Given the `insertAfter` method name, `prev_node` looks fine to me. Not sure if I got your question correctly.

Comment: @Alfeu, the question is admittedly confusing. Since I haven't named the nodes, I can't input them by their Node names into prev_node, so if the third node (80) is my prev_node what value has to be passed in the parameter to make the method understand which node I am talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you want to know what should be passed for the argument when you want to insert data at different positions. With only insertAfter method provided you need to traverse through the linked list manually. In the example given by you it goes as below:

```
Insert after 11 -> insertAfter(llist.head, 0)
Insert after 73 -> insertAfter(llist.head.next, 0)
Insert after 80 -> insertAfter(llist.head.next.next, 0)
Insert after 41 -> insertAfter(llist.head.next.next.next, 0)
Insert after 22 -> insertAfter(llist.head.next.next.next.next, 0)
```

But this is not a correct approach. You need to provide traversal mechanisms as well as other methods which can add the value at the head, at the end of the list, at a given position etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need a method that starts from the head of the linked list, traverses to the desired position, and returns that Node. You can then use that Node as an argument to your `insertAfter()` method.

```
public Node getNodeAtPosition(Node head, int position){
    if (head == null || position < 0) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("head == null or position < 0");
    Node helper = head;
    while (position != 0) {
        if (helper == null) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("position > length of list");
        helper = helper.next;
        position--;
    }
    return helper;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Shail, this idea crossed my mind too but I needed some validation going ahead. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure that the linked list is not empty, and 0<=position<length of linked list.

Comment: @Dusty Please upvote this answer and mark it as accepted if it has solved your doubt. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Shail, I've upvoted your answer but it wont show due to SO policy stating votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score. Cheers